# Binding multiple Models in View page Xamarin

Tags: api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to bind ListView using `ItemsSource="{Binding modelname}"` it is working fine with one model(Ads), when I added two Models (Ads) and (AdsImg) it's return nothing :

```
 public class Ads
     {
        public string Titel { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<AdsImg> AdsImg { get; set; }
       }

public class AdsImg
    {    
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string ImgPath { get; set; }
       public int AdId { get; set; }
   }
```

I combine them in ViewModels (AdsViewModel)

```
public class AdsViewModel
{

    public AdsImg AdsImg { get; set; }
    public Ads Ads { get; set; }


}
```

Xaml page :

```
<ListView x:Name="AdsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding AdsViewModel}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                <Image Source="{Binding AdsImg.ImgPath}" />  
                       <Label Text="{Binding Ads.Titel}"  TextColor="Black"></Label>
                       <Label Text="{Binding Ads.Description}" TextColor="Black"></Label>
               </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Xaml.cs

```
public AdsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetAds();
    }
    private async void GetAds()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://example.net/api/Ad");
        var Ads = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AdsViewModel>>(response);
        AdsListView.ItemsSource = Ads;
    }
```

Update I replaced this code:

```
   AdsImg img = new AdsImg() {ImgPath = "imagePath"};
    Ads ads = new Ads() { Titel = "title",Description = "des" };
```

with this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://example.com/api/Ad");
        var Ads = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AdsViewModel>>(response);
```

but it is not working

Comment: either assign ItemsSource in XAML or in code - don't to both.  In your case, the XAML is wrong and the code appears correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give you some suggestions:

1. Don't name the property's name the same as the class name, for example:  `public AdsImg AdsImg`, it looks confusing when you use `AdsImg`.
2. If you want to bind the ItemSource in xaml, you should bind to a `List<AdsViewModel>` instead of a single ViewModel.

I wrote a example and hope you can get some idea from it:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AdsViewModel vm = new AdsViewModel();
        vm.getData();
        BindingContext = vm;

    }
}

public class AdsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private List<AdsViewModel> _modelDatas;
    public List<AdsViewModel> modelDatas
    {
        get { return _modelDatas; }
        set
        {
            _modelDatas = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("modelDatas");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public AdsImg AdsImgModel { get; set; }
    public Ads AdsModel { get; set; }
        
    public AdsViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void getData() {

        AdsImg img = new AdsImg() {ImgPath = "imagePath"};
        Ads ads = new Ads() { Titel = "title",Description = "des" };

        modelDatas = new List<AdsViewModel>();

        modelDatas.Add( new AdsViewModel() { AdsImgModel = img, AdsModel = ads });
        modelDatas.Add(new AdsViewModel() { AdsImgModel = img, AdsModel = ads });
        modelDatas.Add(new AdsViewModel() { AdsImgModel = img, AdsModel = ads });

    }
}

public class Ads
{
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<AdsImg> AdsImg { get; set; }
}

public class AdsImg
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImgPath { get; set; }
    public int AdId { get; set; }
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="AdsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding modelDatas}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image Source="{Binding AdsImg.ImgPath}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding AdsModel.Titel}"  TextColor="Black"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding AdsModel.Description}" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                </StackLayout>

            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Sample project has been uploaded [here](https://github.com/XfHua/data-binding-listview)
and please feel free to ask me any question!

Comment: Thank's Jack it is working, but what if I want to get data from API JSON format , I update The qustion

Comment: That's depending on your json format and you should add a breakpoint to check what Ads is.